# Como validar la entrada de datos en C# consola

Tags: c#, visual-studio, consola

Tengo una duda en la validación de entrada de datos en C#, por ejemplo, en un ejercicio de calcuclar una suma en C# modo consola, como se evita que la ejecución se cuelgue y deje funcionar a la hora de insertar letras.

Por ejemplo con este código que saca el promedio de los numeros pares e impares.

```
int cont;
int num;
float contP = 0, acumP = 0;
float contI = 0, acumI = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Digite los numeros que quiera");
cont = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite el numero {0}", (i + 1));
    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        contP++;
        acumP += num;
    } else {
        contI++;
        acumI += num;
    }
}

float promP = acumP / contP;
float promI = acumI / contI;

Console.WriteLine("El promedio de los numeros pares es: " + promP);
Console.WriteLine("El promedio de los numeros impares es: " + promI);
```

¿Qué validación tengo que hacer a la hora que el usuario inserte una letra diga "Uste digito una letra"?. Lo he buscado pero no sale, lo he hallado pero para `Form` nada más y no en consola

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes bien planteada la idea de como trabajar con la consola. Al momento de validar la consola, para ser más exacto, con [int.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) hay que asignar el resultado en una bandera y tu cont como variable de salida.

```
bool EsEntero = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cont);

if(!EsEntero)
    Console.WriteLine("El dato ingresado no es un entero");
```

[Ejemplo con tú codigo, ajusta lo que necesites](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6pRgYD)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un loop para mantener el flujo hasta que se ingrese un entero válido:

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite los numeros que quiera");
while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cont))
{
    Console.WriteLine("El dato ingresado no es un entero");
    Console.WriteLine("Digite los numeros que quiera.");
}
```

Y si deseas reutilizar la lógica puedes extraerlo a un método:

```
static int IngresarEntero(string mensaje)
{
    int valor;
    Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out valor))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El dato ingresado no es un entero");
        Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
    }

    return valor;
}
```

y despues invocarlo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cont;
    int num;
    float contP = 0, acumP = 0;
    float contI = 0, acumI = 0;

    cont = IngresarEntero("Digite los numeros que quiera");

    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
    {
    ...
```

Quizás quieras darle una opción de escape.

```
static int IngresarEntero(string mensaje)
{
    int value = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
    string valor = Console.ReadLine();
    while (!Int32.TryParse(valor, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El dato ingresado no es un entero");
        Console.WriteLine($"{mensaje} o (q) para salir");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        if (valor.ToLower().Equals("q"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Programa terminado. Presione una tecla para continuar.");
            Console.Read();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

De esta forma el programa terminara si el usuario ingresa una 'q'